# PHP ImageMagick Multiple sizes for images - Cant get it to work

Tags: php, codeigniter, imagemagick, image-resizing

Hi all : ) Thank you in advance for any assistance with this question.

I am using CodeIgniter and have images uploading, rotating and resizing successfully.
It is when I try to create multiple sizes fro an image that I am a little lost.

Here is my code:

```
// First I make two copies of the origional image - there is no problem here - these always work. I always have the successfully copied images.

                $Copy_Mid_Size_File = "Some_Path_For_The_Newly_Copied_Mid_Size_Image"

                if(!copy($source_image, $Copy_Mid_Size_File)){
                    echo "failed to copy $Copy_Mid_Size_File - Please contact the system administrator. \n";
                    die();
                }

                $Copy_Thumbnail_Size_File = "Some_Path_For_The_Newly_Copied_Thumbnail_Size_Image"

                if(!copy($source_image, $Copy_Thumbnail_Size_File)){
                    echo "failed to copy $Copy_Thumbnail_Size_File - Please contact the system administrator. \n";
                    die();
                }

                // Now I resize for the mid size image
                $config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';           
                $config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';

                $config['source_image'] = $Copy_Mid_Size_File;
                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['quality'] = '100%';
                $config['master_dim'] = 'auto';
                $config['width'] = 200;
                $config['height'] = 200;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();// This has never reported an error yet
                    echo "Image Re-size for Mid Size Image FAILED!";// This has never reported an error yet
                    die();
                }else{
                    echo" Mid-Size Re-size Worked!";
                }


                // Now I try to resize for the Thumbnail
                $config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';           
                $config['library_path'] = '/usr/bin';

                $config['source_image'] = $Copy_Thumbnail_Size_File;

                $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
                $config['quality'] = '100%';
                $config['master_dim'] = 'auto';
                $config['width'] = 50;
                $config['height'] = 50;

                $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

                if(!$this->image_lib->resize()){
                    echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();// This has never reported an error yet
                    echo "Image Re-size for Thumbnail Size Image FAILED!";// This has never reported an error yet
                    die();
                }else{
                    echo" Thumbnail Re-size Worked!";
                }
```

I always end up with the proper number of images correctly named - The thumbnail image just does not re-size - there is no error reported. It always says that is succeeded.

If I put the thumbnail re-size code first - the thumbnail re-sizes correctly - but then the mid-size image does not.

I realize there are other ways to load the libraries - but I don't see why the first re-size works but the second does not.

Any ideas?

Thanks.
Regards,
Ken

Comment: placed this line of code before creating thumbnail 
`$this->image_lib->clear()`

Comment: Hi Hameed - tried that and I get the error "Image processing failed.  Please verify that your server supports the chosen protocol and that the path to your image library is correct." 

Strange that the first one is exactly the same and there is not an error - yet the second one calls a "path" or "protocol" error. Why would one pass and not the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need to load the library once, but then you need to *initialize* it with the new config each time. So your code will look like this:

```
// load the library
$this->load->library('image_lib');

// first image:
// set some config
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
...

// initialize the library with this config
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// Do the resize:
$this->image_lib->resize();

// clear the config:
$this->image_lib->clear();

// second image:
// set some config
$config['image_library'] = 'imagemagick';
...

// re-initialize the library with the new config
$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
// Do the resize:
$this->image_lib->resize();
```

I suspect you could even just update `$config['width']` and `$config['height']` without having to clear, but I've not tested that!

As a side note, you don't really have to copy the image into the correct directories first; the CodeIgniter image library can create a new one for you, if you set your config like this:

```
$config['new_image'] = '/path/to/new_image.jpg';
```

This will save the image into the new path without having to create copies all over the place.

Reference: http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/image_lib.html

Comment: Thank you very much froddd.

It all makes good sense to load the library once and initialize the library with whatever config or changed config values you want to use.

Thanks again for your help - I appreciate it.

I some how was confused with the examples on the page you link to - as I used those for my first attempt - somehow I missed the "initialize". But still confused as to how the first one copied without using the "initialize".

Anyway - thanks again! : )

Comment: Also - it seems as though "$this->image_lib->clear();" is not needed. I tried it with and without the "$this->image_lib->clear();" and got the same results.

But, I was expecting that "$this->image_lib->clear();" would clear the config values? 

So is it clear what exactly "$this->image_lib->clear();" does?



And you were also right that I only needed to change the width height and 'new_image' path.

Comment: I wouldn;t mind asking you another question froddd - because it seems that you have some good experience with this - 

Is there a relatively easy way to show the progress of an uploading image using codeigniter and imagemagick?

thanks

Comment: The `clear()` method probably only clears the config values, hence why it's not actually needed if you overwrite all of them, or if you reuse similar ones.

Regarding file upload progress: that's another subject entirely! Best option, IMO, is to use a jQuery plugin like [jQuery File Upload](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)